# "Sub-classes" and self in Python

Tags: python, descriptor

**Note:** I see that I need to more clearly work out what it is that I want each property/descriptor/class/method to do before I ask how to do it!  I don't think my question can be answered at this time.  Thanks all for helping me out.

Thanks to icktoofay and BrenBarn, I'm starting to understand discriptors and properties, but now I have a slightly harder question to ask:

I see now how these work:

```
class Blub(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print('Blub gets ' + instance._blub)
        return instance._blub

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print('Blub becomes ' + value)
        instance._blub = value

class Quish(object):
    blub = Blub()

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.blub = value
```

And how a = Quish('one') works (produces "Blub becomes one") but take a gander at this code:

```
import os
import glob

class Index(object):
    def __init__(self, dir=os.getcwd()):
        self.name = dir    #index name is directory of indexes
        # index is the list of indexes
        self.index = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.name, 'BatchStarted*'))
        # which is the pointer to the index (index[which] == BatchStarted_12312013_115959.txt)
        self.which = 0
        # self.file = self.File(self.index[self.which])
    def get(self):
        return self.index[self.which]
    def next(self):
        self.which += 1
        if self.which < len(self.index):
            return self.get()
        else:
            # loop back to the first
            self.which = 0
            return None
    def back(self):
        if self.which > 0:
            self.which -= 1
        return self.get()

class File(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        # if the file exists, we'll use it.
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            self.name = file
        # otherwise, our name is none and we return.
        else:
            self.name = None
            return None
        # 'file' attribute is the actual file object
        self.file = open(self.name, 'r')
        self.line = Lines(self.file)

class Lines(object):
    # pass through the actual file object (not filename)
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        # line is the list if this file's lines
        self.line = self.file.readlines()
        self.which = 0
        self.extension = Extension(self.line[self.which])
    def __get__(self):
        return self.line[self.which]
    def __set__(self, value):
        self.which = value
    def next(self):
        self.which += 1
        return self.__get__()
    def back(self):
        self.which -= 1
        return self.__get__()

class Extension(object):
    def __init__(self, lineStr):
        # check to make sure a string is passed
        if lineStr:
            self.lineStr = lineStr
            self.line = self.lineStr.split('|')
            self.pathStr = self.line[0]
            self.path = self.pathStr.split('\\')
            self.fileStr = self.path[-1]
            self.file = self.fileStr.split('.')
        else:
            self.lineStr = None                    
    def __get__(self):
        self.line = self.lineStr.split('|')
        self.pathStr = self.line[0]
        self.path = self.pathStr.split('\\')
        self.fileStr = self.path[-1]
        self.file = self.fileStr.split('.')
        return self.file[-1]
    def __set__(self, ext):
        self.file[-1] = ext
        self.fileStr = '.'.join(self.file)
        self.path[-1] = fileStr
        self.pathStr = '\\'.join(self.path)
        self.line[0] = self.pathStr
        self.lineStr = '|'.join(self.line)
```

Firstly, there may be some typos in here because I've been working on it and leaving it half-arsed.  That's not my point.  My point is that in icktoofay's example, nothing gets passed to Blub().  Is there any way to do what I'm doing here, that is set some "self" attributes and after doing some processing, taking that and passing it to the next class?  Would this be better suited for a property?

I would like to have it so that:

```
>>> i = Index()         # i contains list of index files
>>> f = File(i.get())   # f is now one of those files
>>> f.line
'\\\\server\\share\\folder\\file0.txt|Name|Sean|Date|10-20-2000|Type|1'
>>> f.line.extension
'txt'
>>> f.line.extension = 'rtf'
>>> f.line
'\\\\server\\share\\folder\\file0.rtf|Name|Sean|Date|10-20-2000|Type|1'
```

Comment: Thought experiment for you, perhaps: is `f.line` a `str` or a `Lines`? If you added (say) a `find` method to `Lines`, would you expect `f.line.find()` to call `str`'s implementation of `find` or `Lines`'s implementation of `find`? Why?

Comment: I updated my question to reflect my realization of the ambiguity in what I'm trying to do.  I need to solidify how I want the program to work before I start asking how to do stuff in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but the issue there is less about properties/descriptors and more about creating classes that give the behavior you want.

So, when you do `f.line`, that is some object.  When you do `f.line.extension`, that is doing `(f.line).extension` --- that is, it first evalautes `f.line` and then gets the `extension` attribute of whatever `f.line` is.

The important thing here is that **`f.line` cannot know whether you are later going to try to access its `extension`**.  So you can't have `f.line` do one thing for "plain" `f.line` and another thing for `f.line.extension`.  The `f.line` part has to be the same in both, and the `extension` part can't change that.

The solution for what you seem to want to do is to make `f.line` return some kind of object that in some way looks or works like a string, but also allows setting attributes and updating itself accordingly.  Exactly how you do this depends on how much you need `f.lines` to behave like a string and how much you need it to do other stuff.  Basically you need `f.line` to be a "gatekeeper" object that handles some operations by acting like a string (e.g., you apparently want it to *display* as a string), and handles other objects in custom ways (e.g., you apparently want to be able to set an `extension` attribute on it and have that update its contents).

Here's a simplistic example:

```
class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, txt):
        self.base, self.extension = txt.split('.')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.base + "." + self.extension
```

Now you can do:

```
>>> line = Line('file.txt')
>>> print line
file.txt
>>> line.extension
'txt'
>>> line.extension = 'foo'
>>> print line
file.foo
```

However, notice that I did `print line`, not just `line`.  By writing a `__str__` method, I defined the behavior that happens when you do `print line`.  But if you evaluate it "raw" without printing it, you'll see it's not really a string:

```
>>> line
<__main__.Line object at 0x000000000233D278>
```

You could override this behavior as well (by defining `__repr__`), but do you want to?  That depends on how you want to use `line`.  The point is that you need to decide what you want your `line` to do in what situations, and then craft a class that does that.

Comment: I might end up using the __str__() function.  This looks great, thank you.